# Normalise max value of probability function for all frames

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, contour

I have working code that plots a bivariate gaussian distribution. The distribution is produced by adjusting the `COV` `matrix` to account for specific variables. Specifically, every XY coordinate is applied with a `radius`. The `COV` `matrix` is then adjusted by a `scaling` factor to expand the `radius` in `x-direction` and contract in `y-direction`. The direction of this is measured by `theta`. The output is expressed as a `probability` density function `(PDF)`.

I have normalised the `PDF` values. However, I'm calling a separate `PDF` for each frame. As such, the maximum value changes and hence the probability will be transformed differently for each frame.

Question: Using @Prasanth's suggestion. Is it possible to create normalized arrays for each frame before plotting, and then plot these arrays?

Below is the function I'm currently using to normalise the `PDF` for a single frame.

```
normPDF = (PDFs[0]-PDFs[1])/max(PDFs[0].max(),PDFs[1].max())
```

Comment: For the record, I did not down vote. Reading your question, however, I think it is quite hard to grasp what you are really asking about… there is a lot of code and not much explanation.

Comment: Ok. Thanks @mortysporty. I've added some more context. How is this?

Comment: Please avoid any context, that doesn't help answering your question. The first paragraph is not programming related, it's a mathematical explanation.

Comment: If I understand your setup correctly then "normalise all frames at once with this global maximum value" is an invalid mathematical operation. These "frames" are different bivariate PDFs and need to be normalized separately.  Perhaps you are asking how to create normalized arrays for each frame before plotting, and then during plotting we simply plot the arrays? Or I got your setup wrong!

Comment: @Prasanth, is it possible to display the method to create normalised arrays for each frame before plotting in answer format?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to create normalized arrays for each frame before plotting, and then plot these arrays?

Indeed is possible. In your case you probably need to rescale your arrays between two values, say `-1` and `1`, before plotting. So that the minimum becomes `-1`, the maximum `1` and the intermediate values are scaled accordingly.
You could also choose `0` and `1` or whatever as minimum and maximum, but let's go with `-1` and `1` so that a the middle value is `0`.

To do this, in your code replace:

```
normPDF = (PDFs[0]-PDFs[1])/max(PDFs[0].max(),PDFs[1].max())
```

with:

```
renormPDF = PDFs[0]-PDFs[1]
renormPDF -= renormPDF.min()
normPDF = (renormPDF * 2 / renormPDF.max()) -1
```

This three lines ensure that `normPDF.min() == -1` and `normPDF.max() == 1`.

Now when plotting the animation the axis on the right of your image does not change.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Valentino. Apologies for this oversight. I didn't have it in the question but I've _pegged_ values at 0 to have the same colour. This ensures the _flickering_ of the background doesn't occur. It is fixed at 0. Is there anyway I can keep this function?

Comment: Not really, no way to preserve the scaling if the zeroes are forced to stay zeroes.

Comment: Would be fine for you to delete and redraw the colorbar each time? Upper and lower limits will change, but not be drawn on top of the previous ones

Comment: Is it possible to first calculate the `PDFs` for all frames, compute the max values for all frames and then normalise all frames at once with this global maximum value?

Comment: Yes, is possible. But I didn't dig through your code in detail since it's long and uncommented, it's hard to follow everything. I think you need to edit a lot of things to do that.

Comment: Ok. Thanks @Valentino

Comment: But let me say another thing: even if you compute the max values for all frame and use those, the colorbar problem is not solved. the colorbar is drawn each frame using the data of those frame, so if maximum and minimum changes significanly, the colorbar changes whatever normalization you use.

Comment: Could you not plot the colorbar using the maximum/minimum vales?

Comment: Maybe il possible, but I don't know how. Usually colorbars are built automatically from the current dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is to find the maximum values of `PDFs[0].max()` and `PDFs[1].max()` for all frames.

Why don't you run `plotmvs` on all your planned frames in order to find the absolute maximum for `PDFs[0]` and `PDFs[1]` and then run your `animation` with these absolute maxima to normalize your plots? This way, the `colorbar` will be the same for all frames.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Tom Combriat. That's what I'm envisaging to achieve. I just don't know where to start.